# Comparing the InnerHTML of an object in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, comparison, sharepoint-2013

I am able to get the `.html()` of a SharePoint textbox, which in the DOM simply appears as a `<div>`.  When the textbox is empty, the InnerHTML of that `<div>` simply appears as `<p></p>`.

Because this particular textbox does not always appear (I control its appearance based on the selected value of a previous checkbox on the form), I can't make it required, so I'm doing it dynamically by checking if it is filled in or not on-save.  This means seeing if that InnerHTML is `<p></p>` or something like `<p>asdf<span id="ms-rterangecursor-start" RteNodeId="1"></span><span id="ms-rterangecursor-end"></span></p>`, where `asdf` is the text that is entered (SharePoint puts in all the gobbly-gook in-between).

What I thought I could do was to check it like this, with `explainField` representing the `<div>` as a jQuery variable, similar to what was done at http://makandracards.com/makandra/13445-compare-two-jquery-objects-for-equality :

```
var $divNode = $('div');
var $pNode = $('p');
var $testNode = $divNode.html($pNode);
if (explainField.is($(testNode))) { 
    // we got <p></p>
    return false;  // go no further
} else {
    return true;  // we're ok
}
```

But this comparison does not work.  When there is no text, the statement should be met and return false.  Instead, it returns true and thinks we have text when we don't.  How can I make this comparison work and return false if it finds `<p></p>`?

Comment: Your code doesn't make much sense. `$divNode` is a collection of all the DIVs in the document, and `$pNode` is all the paragraphs in the document. Then you're setting the HTML of all the DIVs to be all the paragraphs. `.html()` returns the elements it's operating on when you call it with an argument, for chaining, so `$testNode` is the same as `$divNode`.

Comment: I suspect you're confusing `$('div')` (a selector) with `$('<div>')` (a constructor).

Comment: How about `explainField.text() == ''`?

Comment: Need your HTML at some more code...

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, Barmar - that was exactly it. I was confusing the selector with the constructor. I may check on Monday if the other way than LShetty's solution (making the selector a constructor, to compare nodes) would have worked.

Comment: Using `$('<div>')` and putting in a `$('<p>')` into it and trying to compare that to the object I was getting back didn't work, either, but I didn't really expect it to.  All of this was a last ditch effort I was doing when I couldn't figure out how to get the `.html()` comparison to work on the nodes, themselves.  But I did find `if (explainField.text() == '') { ... }` would have worked, and added that to the fiddle I created off of the one LShetty started: http://jsfiddle.net/navyjax2/9unnh92z/ - @Barmar, you should put that as an alternate solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, try the following which is a bit easier than what you were trying.

```
var $divNode = $('div');
var html = $divNode.html();

if ( $(html).children().length > 0 ) {
    alert ("not empty");
} else {
    alert ("empty");
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/xL3L213h/)

Comment: Sure, did you try `var $testNode = $divNode.html('<p></p>');`?

Comment: I just tried as you suggested, then using `if ($testNode == explainHTML) { ... }`, where explainHTML is `explainField.html()`.  They are not equal when I leave the textfield blank, though they should be.  I also tried `if (explainField.children(0).is(':empty') )`, and this also did not work.

Comment: So, just to be clear, all you need to do is to check if your div's inner HTML is just an empty P tag or not. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  I first tried `if (explainHTML == '<p></p>') { ... } ` and this didn't work.

Comment: So, this should help [http://jsfiddle.net/xL3L213h/](http://jsfiddle.net/xL3L213h/) ?

Comment: `$(html).children().length > 0` worked after I put `$` on my variables.  I updated the fiddle to make it more in conformance with what I was doing/facing.  Thanks for the help.  Put that into an answer and I'll mark it as the accepted solution.

Comment: Here is my fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/navyjax2/9unnh92z/ . It will indicate if the selected node is empty or not depending on which one is uncommented.

Comment: For others' benefit - I found I needed to account for a new case - one where it puts `<p>asdf</p>` instead of that long codestring. So I had to modify it a little so it could account for all 3 cases. Instead of `$(html).children().length > 0`, I'm now using `if ($(html).html().length > 0) { ... }`.  It's odd, though, because it sees `<p></p>` as an HTML length of 0 when I would have expected 7. But it works for my purposes.  Since this is a new case than I declared in my initial question, I'll leave the above as the accepted answer, since that is the answer for the 2 cases. Fiddle is updated.